# Assign Null value to the Integer Column in the DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, types

I have a datatable with One ColumnName "CustomerID" with Integer DataType.
Dynamically I want to add rows to the DataTable. For that, I had created one DataRow object like:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataRow DR = dt.NewRow();
  DR["CustomerID"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
```

But if the TextBox contains empty string, it throws the error. In that case, I want to assign Null value to the CustomerID. How to do this?

Comment: @Marc why not you recommend him something instead using DataTable?

Comment: @Marc: Yes. Iam using DataTable.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A null/empty string is in the wrong format; you would need to detect that scenario and compensate:

```
    DR["CustomerID"] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
        ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToInt32(text);
```

Comment: If we have to construct that DataTable manually like `MyDataTable.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(int))`, should we have that `CustomerID` field be defined as a Nullable type like `int?`?

Answer (score 5):

```
DR["CustomerID"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)
                   ? Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
                   : DBNull.Value;
```

But you should check also that the value is a valid integer:

```
int value;
if(int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value))
{
    DR["CustomerID"] = value;
}
else
{
    DR["CustomerID"] = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like that:

```
DR["CustomerID"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) ?
    null : Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, of course, the field needs to be set as nullable in the DB.

And then, set it to `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check first

```
if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
   DR["CustomerID"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text); 
}
else
{
  DR["CustomerID"] = null;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Int32 Temp = 0;
if !(Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,Temp))
    DR["CustomerID"] = DBNull.Value
else
    DR["CustomerID"] = Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBNull.

```
DR["CustomerID"] = (TextBox.Text.Length == 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow DR = dt.NewRow();

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    DR["CustomerID"] = DBNull.Value;
else
    DR["CustomerID"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the Integer variable as int? it is automatically boxed by the C# compiler and you are able to assign null to that variable. For example:

```
int? custID = null;
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (TextBox1.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        DR["CustomerID"] = null;
    }
    else
    {
        DR["CustomerID"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: null is not accepted, you must use DBNull.value

Answer (score 0):

When `null` is not allowed to be inserted into `DR["CustomerID"]`, you could use `(int?)null` instead like this:

```
DR["CustomerID"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) ?
(int?) null : Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: null is not an accepted value, you must use DBNull.value