# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in c# program

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please Help me out,This is my database table in sql-server

```
(empcode    varchar(50)
firstname   varchar(50)
lastname    varchar(50)
gender  varchar(50)
address varchar(50)
contactno   numeric(18, 0)
bloodgroup  varchar(50)
dateofbirth date
country varchar(50)
qid varchar(50)
passportno  varchar(50)
passportexpiredate  date
designation varchar(50)
doj date    
doexpid date
pf_acc_no   numeric(18, 0)  
agreementstartdate  date    
agreementenddate    date    
department  varchar(50) 
basic_sal   numeric(18, 0)  
remarks varchar(50) 
empimage    image)
```

and I'm Trying to insert my data through c# windows forms but i'm getting error as "**Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**"
Here below is my c# code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn.Open();
        if (!empid())
        {
            DialogResult d = new DialogResult();
            d = MessageBox.Show("Do You Declare Yourself All The Information Of This Employee Is Correct To Save?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (d == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int i = 0;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(
     empcode,firstname,lastname,gender,address,contactno,bloodgroup,
    dateofbirth, country,qid,passportno,passportexpiredate,designation,
    doj,doexpid,pf_acc_no, agreementstartdate,agreementenddate,
    department,basic_sal,remarks,empimage) 
    VALUES('" + txtempcode.Text + "','" + txtfrstname.Text + "', 
    '" + txtlstname.Text + "','" + combogender.Text + "','" +
    txtaddr.Text + "','" + txtcont.Text + "','" + txtblodgrp.Text + "', '" + 
    dob.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + txtcountry.Text + "','" + tqid.Text + "','" + 
    txtpassportno.Text + "', '" + passexpdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + 
    combodesig.Text + "', '" + doj.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', '" + doexpqid.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', '" + 
    txtqibacc.Text + "', '" + agreestartdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "','" + agreeenddate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + combobranch.Text + "','" + txtnetsalary.Text + "','" + txtremark.Text + "',@empimage) ", cn);

                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empimage", pic);
                i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted Employee Record" + i);
                }
                cn.Close();
                showdata();
                clear();
            }
        }
    }

public bool empid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAFIYA-PC;Initial Catalog=dbEmployee;User ID=sa;Password=sa$123"))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "select empcode from Employee where empcode = '" + txtempcode.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                empCode = dr["empcode"].ToString();
                if (empCode != "0")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Id already Existed Please use Another One!!!!!!");
                    return false;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }                        
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use named parameters instead of concatenating strings. Furthermore your code is not very readable. Please reformat it.

Comment: Also your DB types don't seem appropriate. Use `nvarchar` for "human-readable" strings instead of `varchar`; also note that `text` and `image` are both deprecated, use `varbinary` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: the comment below is quite right, the immediate issue is that you have single quotes around the data you are trying to put in the `contactno numeric(18, 0)` field which is telling SQL to interpret that value as a varchar.

Change `"','" + txtcont.Text + "','"` to `"'," + txtcont.Text + ",'"` (i.e. remove the single quotes either side of the text box value) and do the same for any other numeric fields.

However, as is mentioned in other responses, this general approach of concatenating together a sql command string [is not recommended from a security point of view](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29).  The preferred option is to use a [parametrised query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using a parametrised query will also make it easier to deal with any nullable fields, [as per this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717179/how-to-insert-null-value-in-database-through-parameterized-query).

(Edited to correct the answer in response to comment from Steffen)

Comment: he is combining it to a string anyway so the C# type (in theory) doesn't matter. He would just need to not put those ' around values that aren't varchars on the database side.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler you're quite right, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @IqbalKhan, that's great news! Feel free to accept this as the answer and upvote if it helped :)

Comment: but it showing --->Incorrect syntax near ','. whenever i put null values in contactno,pf_acc_no and basic_sal

Comment: @IqbalKhan that's another issue.  If the fields can be null you'd really be much better using a parametrised query.  That will also be a lot safer as it guards against SQL injection attacks.  Have a look at this stack overflow question for some good info on how to convert your query string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032054/insert-statement-wont-insert-null-value

Comment: @IqbalKhan here's another example too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717179/how-to-insert-null-value-in-database-through-parameterized-query

Comment: @tom_redox That link shows the inserting the date time field values,does it works with my numeric one.

Comment: @IqbalKhan it should work fine, the only difference may be how you determine if the value is null, you might need to do a check to say if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourValue)) rather than if(yourValue.HasValue).  Give the parametrised approach a go, and if you hit any issues post a whole new question.

Comment: @tom_redox after your suggestion i considered to go for parameterised query way now I'm struggling for date field to put null value as you provided the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717179/how-to-insert-null-value-in-database-through-parameterized-query is helpful but when i'm saying like if (dob.Hasvalue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", dob);
                    }
       else
    { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", DBNull.Value);  HasValue does not contain definition
                    }

Comment: @IqbalKhan what issue are you actually having with it, are you getting an error etc?

Comment: @IqbalKhan How are you getting the value of dob can you paste in the lines of code where you declare dob and set its value?

Comment: i took datetimepicker value where if user not select the dob it by default takes today's date but i need to put condition that if user not selected the date it should become null

Comment: you need to use dob.Value instead of just dob - dob is the control, but you want its value

Comment: If that doesn't work try if(dob.Value == null) instead of if(dob.Value.HasValue)

Comment: @IqbalKhan re the default value: that's an entirely different question, so best to ask that one in a separate question and include a sample of the code you've tried so far to solve that.  If the SQL insert is now working this question is probably answered?

Comment: @tom_redox--->   dob takes today's value if user not valued, In my scenario i need null value if user not given any value in it,please help me

Comment: Belatedly, I thought a DateTimePicker control couldn't actualy be set to null, I think it always returns a DateTime?  I dpon't know much about that though, we don't use them (we use Infragistics controls).  Like I say, it's a different question to the original, close this question, post a new one and then lots more people will see it and be able to help.  By all means post a link back here and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use parameters? It prevents your code from SQL Injection and you don't have to convert values and code is much more readable. Look at sample (it is for select statement but the same works for insert/update/delete statement):

```
var connectionString = "some connection string";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection)) {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            int weight = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string name = reader.GetString(1);
            string breed = reader.GetString(2);
            Console.WriteLine("Weight = {0}, Name = {1}, Breed = {2}",
            weight,
            name,
            breed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly storing the text value of your controls in your numeric fields (contactno, pf_acc_no and basic_sal). Are the values really sql-string representations of numeric values?

I would try to convert them to numeric value

```
double dValue = 0.0;
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dValue);
```

and then, in the sql string convert to their sql-string representations with `dValue.ToString()` or a special dedicated method.

Answer (score 0):

As per your table structure, there are 3 fields that are of numeric datatype. These are - *contactno*, *pf_acc_no* and *basic_sal*

And the values for these fileds are  `txtcont.Text`, `txtqibacc.Text` and `txtnetsalary.Text` respectively, And your are also putting `'` around them, that is why they are being treated as varchar filed.

While constructing the sql statement, you should pass the values for these fields as numeric, which is to say without `'` marks. So just remove `'` before and after these fields and your query should work fine.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(
     empcode,firstname,lastname,gender,address,contactno,bloodgroup,
    dateofbirth, country,qid,passportno,passportexpiredate,designation,
    doj,doexpid,pf_acc_no, agreementstartdate,agreementenddate,
    department,basic_sal,remarks,empimage) 
    VALUES('" + txtempcode.Text + "','" + txtfrstname.Text + "', 
    '" + txtlstname.Text + "','" + combogender.Text + "','" +
    txtaddr.Text + "'," + txtcont.Text + ",'" + txtblodgrp.Text + "', '" + 
    dob.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + txtcountry.Text + "','" + tqid.Text + "','" + 
    txtpassportno.Text + "', '" + passexpdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + 
    combodesig.Text + "', '" + doj.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', '" + doexpqid.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', " + 
    txtqibacc.Text + ", '" + agreestartdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "','" + agreeenddate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,'" + combobranch.Text + "'," + txtnetsalary.Text + ",'" + txtremark.Text + "',@empimage) ", cn);
```

In case you need to pass null to these numeric fields, use `DBNull.Value` as shown here - 
[Assign Null value to the Integer Column in the DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357899/assign-null-value-to-the-integer-column-in-the-datatable)

*Constructing queries like these are prone to `SqlInjection`, suggest to use parameterized queries instead.*

Comment: but it showing --->Incorrect syntax near ','. whenever i put some null values in contactno,pf_acc_no and basic_sal

Comment: Use `DBNull.Value` instead where you want to pass null for these values.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your code is very vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. But I don't changing your programming style; I'm changing just your insertion query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    INSERT INTO Employee
        (empcode, firstname, lastname, gender, address, contactno,
         bloodgroup, dateofbirth, country, qid, passportno, passportexpiredate, 
         designation, doj, doexpid, pf_acc_no, agreementstartdate, agreementenddate, 
         department, basic_sal, remarks, empimage) 
    VALUES
        ('" + txtempcode.Text + "',
         '" + txtfrstname.Text + "', 
         '" + txtlstname.Text + "',
         '" + combogender.Text + "',
         '" + txtaddr.Text + "',
         "  + txtcont.Text + ",
         '" + txtblodgrp.Text + "', 
         '" + dob.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,
         '" + txtcountry.Text + "',
         '" + tqid.Text + "',
         "  + txtpassportno.Text + ", 
         '" + passexpdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,
         '" + combodesig.Text + "', 
         '" + doj.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', 
         '" + doexpqid.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', 
         '" + txtqibacc.Text + "', 
         '" + agreestartdate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "',
         '" + agreeenddate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ,
         '" + combobranch.Text + "',
         "  + txtnetsalary.Text + ",
         '" + txtremark.Text + "',
         @empimage) ", cn);
```