# Inserting data in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

SQL Server database table is :

```
inward_id, int(Primary Key),
gate_inward_done, varchar(50),
gate_entry_no, varchar(100),
gate_entry_date, date,
inward_date, date,
vendor_code, varchar(max),
vendor_name, varchar(max),
dc_no, varchar(max),
dc_date, date,
bill_received, varchar(max),
invoice_no, varchar(max),
invoice_date, date,
inv_total_amount, numeric(18,2),
gst_applicable, varchar(max),
cgst, numeric(18,2),
sgst, numeric(18,2),
igst, numeric(18,2),
inv_net_amount, numeric(18,2),
nu_freight, numeric(18,2),
fraction_amount, numeric(18,2),
approvar_department, varchar(max),
vc_remarks_master, varchar(max)
```

When I press button save in C# application, data is not saved in database and shows error "converting data varchar to numeric".

This is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO inward_master values ('"+cmbGateEntry.Text+"','"+txtGateEntryNo.Text+"','"+dtpGateEntryDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"','"+dtpInwardDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"','"+cmbVendorCode.Text+"','"+txtVendorName.Text+"','"+txtDcNo.Text+"','"+dtpDcDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"','"+cmbbill_received.Text+"','"+txtInvoice_No.Text+"','"+dtpInvoiceDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"','"+ txtinv_total_amount.Text +"','"+cmbgst_applicable.Text+"','" + txtcgst.Text + "','" + txtsgst.Text + "','" + txtigst.Text + "','" + txtinv_net_amount.Text + "','" + txtnu_freight.Text + "', '" + txtfraction_amount.Text + "','"+cmbApproverDept.Text+"','"+txtvc_remarks_master.Text+"')";

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

Please give solution. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hello Everyone Please help me

Comment: where you fill inward_id ?

Comment: inward_id is auto increment id? right.

Comment: Make sure your count of text boxes is equal to your column count

Comment: @CodeMan  It is auto increment field

Comment: Please use [sql parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820944/how-do-i-re-write-a-sql-query-as-a-parameterized-query). At the moment your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and "unexpected behaviour".

Comment: @ojlovecd  it's also ok but may be error in converting  numeric  to varchar or varchar to numeric

Comment: Use named parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting data type varchar to numeric in c# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737823/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeric-in-c-sharp-program)

Comment: @John  Sir How do I do that?

Comment: @Dharamraj look at the link I provided.

Comment: @DharamrajPatel, your parameter sequence and your db table sequence is wrong, either same sequence give or define db column before values in insert statemtent.

Comment: @DharamrajPatel , you can try my solution. I have created Demo for this and it works for me ..

Answer (score 0):

**A** it is a bad practice to use `Concatenation` for the query use parameterized approach it is better and a cleaner approach than the one you are using.

And **B** the error clearly states that you are trying to insert a string value to Numeric Column which in your case is something like this you have used `'" + txtfraction_amount.Text + "'` which should be `" + txtfraction_amount.Text + "`(removed the single quotes as they are used for string) as its a numeric value(*this is just an example correct the query and it will work*).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/2417602) is a good example/explanation of a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

If inward_id is auto increment, you must use this:

```
INSERT INTO inward_master (fields....) VALUES(values...)
```